# Are there multiple Frostivus difficulties?

Tags: dota-2

When selecting a difficulty for Frostivus, my options are:

- Normal
- New Game+
- New Game++

Is this a bug?  Are they showing up like this on everyone else's clients?

My main question is what difficulty they actually represent, I'm hoping it's something like:

- Normal
- Hard
- Very Hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, there's up to three difficulties of Frostivus 2013/Wraith-Night you can select. Harder difficulties result in more Phantom and Shining fragment rewards per round, but also makes each wave tougher (more enemies, and more health per enemy). Once in game, upon clearing the Wraith-Night event, the game will step up the difficulty to the next tier and reset to wave 1.

Valve has stated that New Game+ will result in a 25% bonus in fragment drops, with the hardest difficulty giving you a 200% bonus. However, this doesn't mean New Game++ will give you a 200% fragment bonus, as it is currently unclear what the highest difficulty playable is. Players have already reported beating New Game++ will move the game on to New Game+++. If we assume that each step up in difficulty gives you an additional 25% bonus though, then the hardest difficulty in the game should be **New Game++++++++**.

Comment: Awesome, great explanation.  After you beat a difficulty does the next one appear in the dropdown? Or do you have to beat them all straight through

Comment: By default, you can select Normal, New Game+, and New Game++. As far as I know, reaching harder difficulties won't allow you to select them from the dropdown menu on the queue page so you'll have to beat them all straight through if you want to play any of the hidden difficulties.